# How To Add Url To Google by code

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want add a url via code in google that must be added at this [page](http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl). any help?

Comment: Well, if its on your domain just use your sitemap and let google feed it automatically, it wont be *indexed* any time faster anyways. Behave and google will maybe like you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of a Captcha on the page suggests that Google would prefer you not to submit URL's programmatically.

The page itself reads:

> To help us distinguish between sites
>   submitted by individuals and those
>   automatically entered by software
>   robots, please type the squiggly
>   letters shown here into the box below.